# parse IP and TCP header (especially common tcp header options)of packets captured by libpcap

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, libpcap

I want to use libpcap to capture IP  packet, and the I want to parse the IP header and tcp header.
`

there are IP header and TCP header structures in `<netinet/ip.h>` and `<netinet/tcp.h>`
IP header is relatively easier to parse, but for TCP header,since there are tcp options, 
the common options are MSS, SACK(selective acknowledgement), timestamp, window scaling and NOP.

I want to have a function parse_pkt():

```
struct tcphdr tcp_hdr;
struct ip ip_hdr;
parse_pkt(u_char *pcap_packet, struct ip* p_ip, struct tcp* p_tcp);
```

so after calling the function, if I want to know the source ip address, sequence number, and MSS,

```
scr_ip = ip_hdr.src_ip
seq = tcp_hdr.seq
mss = tcp_hdr.mss
```

are there any similar source codes/snippets which can satisfy my requirements?
thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(First example below) Here's something that I have in the works (in C++11).  This is for UDP packets, but you could adapt it for TCP packets by adding the related struct and `Net::load()` template like the one below.

(Second example below) You didn't specify a target language in the question, but if you're looking for C, then you might use `#pragma pack` on the structures and then cast the pointer+offset as a pointer to the struct and then call ntohs/ntohl on the appropriate fields.  Doing that is probably the fastest solution, but it relies on `#pragma pack`, which is not standard.

### C++11 style

net.h:

```cpp
namespace Net {
  using addr_t = uint32_t;
  using port_t = uint16_t;

  struct ether_header_t {
    uint8_t  dst_addr[6];
    uint8_t  src_addr[6];
    uint16_t llc_len;
  };

  struct ip_header_t {
    uint8_t  ver_ihl;  // 4 bits version and 4 bits internet header length
    uint8_t  tos;
    uint16_t total_length;
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t flags_fo; // 3 bits flags and 13 bits fragment-offset
    uint8_t  ttl;
    uint8_t  protocol;
    uint16_t checksum;
    addr_t   src_addr;
    addr_t   dst_addr;

    uint8_t ihl() const;
    size_t size() const;
  };

  class udp_header_t {
  public:
    port_t   src_port;
    port_t   dst_port;
    uint16_t length;
    uint16_t checksum;
  };

  template< typename T >
  T load( std::istream& stream, bool ntoh = true );
  template<>
  ip_header_t  load( std::istream& stream, bool ntoh );
  template<>
  udp_header_t load( std::istream& stream, bool ntoh );

  std::string to_string( const addr_t& addr );
}
```

net.cpp:

```cpp
namespace Net {

  uint8_t ip_header_t::ihl() const {
    return (ver_ihl & 0x0F);
  }

  size_t ip_header_t::size() const {
    return ihl() * sizeof(uint32_t);
  }

  template<>
  ip_header_t load( std::istream& stream, bool ntoh ) {
    ip_header_t header;
    stream.read((char*)&header.ver_ihl,      sizeof(header.ver_ihl));
    stream.read((char*)&header.tos,          sizeof(header.tos));
    stream.read((char*)&header.total_length, sizeof(header.total_length));
    stream.read((char*)&header.id,           sizeof(header.id));
    stream.read((char*)&header.flags_fo,     sizeof(header.flags_fo));
    stream.read((char*)&header.ttl,          sizeof(header.ttl));
    stream.read((char*)&header.protocol,     sizeof(header.protocol));
    stream.read((char*)&header.checksum,     sizeof(header.checksum));
    stream.read((char*)&header.src_addr,     sizeof(header.src_addr));
    stream.read((char*)&header.dst_addr,     sizeof(header.dst_addr));
    if( ntoh ) {
      header.total_length = ntohs(header.total_length);
      header.id =           ntohs(header.id);
      header.flags_fo =     ntohs(header.flags_fo);
      header.checksum =     ntohs(header.checksum);
      header.src_addr =     ntohl(header.src_addr);
      header.dst_addr =     ntohl(header.dst_addr);
    }
    return header;
  }

  template<>
  udp_header_t load( std::istream& stream, bool ntoh ) {
    udp_header_t header;
    stream.read((char*)&header.src_port, sizeof(header.src_port));
    stream.read((char*)&header.dst_port, sizeof(header.dst_port));
    stream.read((char*)&header.length,   sizeof(header.length));
    stream.read((char*)&header.checksum, sizeof(header.checksum));
    if( ntoh ) {
      header.src_port = ntohs(header.src_port);
      header.dst_port = ntohs(header.dst_port);
      header.length   = ntohs(header.length);
      header.checksum = ntohs(header.checksum);
    }
    return header;
  }
}
```

Client code in packet capture handler:

```cpp
using std::chrono::seconds;
using std::chrono::microseconds;
using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using Net::ether_header_t;
using Net::ip_header_t;
using Net::udp_header_t;

auto packet_time = clock::time_point(seconds(header->ts.tv_sec) + microseconds(header->ts.tv_usec));
std::istringstream stream(std::string((char*)packet, header->caplen));
stream.seekg(sizeof(ether_header_t), std::ios_base::beg);
auto ip_header = Net::load<ip_header_t>(stream);
if( ip_header.size() > 20 ) { 
  stream.seekg(ip_header.size() + sizeof(ether_header_t), std::ios_base::beg);
}
auto udp_header = Net::load<udp_header_t>(stream);
```

### alternative (C style):

(Sorry for any errors.  I typed this from memory, and didn't try to compile or run--but I think you will understand the basic idea):

net.h:

```c
typedef uint32_t addr_t;
typedef uint16_t port_t;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
  uint8_t  dst_addr[6];
  uint8_t  src_addr[6];
  uint16_t llc_len;
} ether_header_t;

typedef struct {
  uint8_t  ver_ihl;  // 4 bits version and 4 bits internet header length
  uint8_t  tos;
  uint16_t total_length;
  uint16_t id;
  uint16_t flags_fo; // 3 bits flags and 13 bits fragment-offset
  uint8_t  ttl;
  uint8_t  protocol;
  uint16_t checksum;
  addr_t   src_addr;
  addr_t   dst_addr;
} ip_header_t;

typedef struct {
  port_t   src_port;
  port_t   dst_port;
  uint16_t length;
  uint16_t checksum;
} udp_header_t;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

client code in packet handler:

```c
ip_header_t   ip_header =  (ip_header_t)*(packet + sizeof(ether_header_t));
ip_header.total_length = ntohs(ip_header.total_length);
ip_header.id           = ntohs(ip_header.id);
ip_header.flags_fo     = ntohs(ip_header.flags_fo);
ip_header.checksum     = ntohs(ip_header.checksum);
ip_header.src_addr     = ntohl(ip_header.src_addr);
ip_header.dst_addr     = ntohl(ip_header.dst_addr);
int ip_size = 4 * (ip_header.ver_ihl & 0x0F);

udp_header_t udp_header = (udp_header_t)*(packet + ip_size + sizeof(ether_header_t));
udp_header.src_port = ntohs(udp_header.src_port);
udp_header.dst_port = ntohs(udp_header.dst_port);
udp_header.length   = ntohs(udp_header.length);
udp_header.checksum = ntohs(udp_header.checksum);
```

### TCP Header Notes

according to `netinet/tcp.h`, the TCP header is roughly:

```c
typedef struct {
  uint16_t src_port;
  uint16_t dst_port;
  uint32_t seq;
  uint32_t ack;
  uint8_t  data_offset;  // 4 bits
  uint8_t  flags;
  uint16_t window_size;
  uint16_t checksum;
  uint16_t urgent_p;
} tcp_header_t;
```

Load this struct into memory using whichever method you prefer and don't forget to fix the byte ordering (ntohs/ntohl) for multi-byte integer types as above.

The TCP options follow, which cannot be loaded into a struct like this.  See the section about TCP options at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).  For MSS, you will want to parse each option until you find option with kind == 2.  Building on the C example above:

```c
typedef struct {
  uint8_t kind;
  uint8_t size;
} tcp_option_t;

uint16_t mss;
uint8_t* opt = (uint8_t*)(packet + ip_size + sizeof(ether_header_t) + sizeof(tcp_header_t))
while( *opt != 0 ) {
  tcp_option_t* _opt = (tcp_option_t*)opt;
  if( _opt->kind == 1 /* NOP */ ) {
     ++opt;  // NOP is one byte;
     continue;
  }
  if( _opt->kind == 2 /* MSS */ ) {
    mss = ntohs((uint16_t)*(opt + sizeof(opt)));
  }
  opt += _opt->size;
}
```

Comment: he is interested in parsing the TCP header option, which is a bit more messy(there are rules of course, but not so easy as the other fields) than the other fields.

Comment: It's not as messy as you might think.  Check out the bottom section of my answer.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, `++opt` will make it +2 actually.

Comment: No mistake.  `opt` is a pointer.  `opt++` increments the pointer and `continue` begins the next iteration.

Comment: if it is an NOP, the address should add 1, but ++opt will make it add 2 because `tcp_option_t` is of 2 bytes

Comment: You're right, the size of NOP is only one byte, but `opt` is a pointer and not an array or iterator, so I expect that `++opt` increases the memory location by one.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more explicit about how far to move the pointer.  I'm unclear as to whether `++` on a pointer-to-struct works like `p = p + 1` or `p = p + sizeof(pointer type)`.  If it works like the latter, then thanks for the catch.

Comment: You also got src_port showing twice inside tcp_header_t, the second should be dst_port

Comment: If you have a pointer value of type "pointer to {type}" that is a given address, adding 1 to that value adds `sizeof({type})` to the address, so `p = p + 1` adds `sizeof({type})` to the address contained in `p`, and the current code in the answer is correct, as `opt` is of type "pointer to `uint8_t`".

Comment: `*(opt + sizeof(opt))` fetches one byte, as `opt` is of type "pointer to `uint8_t`", so it won't fetch the full value of the option.  In addition, that also means `sizeof(opt)` is 1, not 2, so it won't skip the option length.  So what you want is `mss = ((*(opt + sizeof(_opt)))) << 8 + *(opt + sizeof(_opt) + 1)`, which will fetch both bytes from the right offsets and assemble them, *even if the address in `opt` isn't aligned safely for a 2-byte fetch*.

Comment: And if you want to make sure your code handles *malformed* (accidentally or deliberately) packets, you should 1) check whether `opt->_size` for the MSS option is 4 and, if not, ignore the MSS option or report an error and 2) make sure `opt->_size` is at least 2 in *all* cases where the option has a size (if it's zero, for example, that code will loop infinitely).

Comment: Oops, `opt + sizeof(_opt)` should be `opt + sizeof(*_opt)`, and `sizeof(opt)` should be `sizeof(*opt)` in my second comment above - we don't want the sizes of pointers, we want the sizes of what they point to.  I've fixed the code, and also added some macros to indicate what some of those sequences of code are doing.

Comment: Wish I could give you two upvotes. Can you directly read raw bytes of an entire IPV4 packet into these three structs then do `ntohs` or equivalent functions when reading individual fields, or is there a catch to that?

Comment: @ytpillai I probably wouldn't use exactly the same logical structure for clear semantics, but that's more or less what I'd do.